# Trouble Using multer to upload in express

Tags: multer

here is my code

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination:function(req,file,cb){
    cb(null,path.join(path.resolve('./'),"/images"))
  },
  filename:function(req,file,cb){
    cb(null,file.fieldname+"-"+ Date.now())
  }
});
```

in "/images",there are 2 files

[image]

they are same files

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: i wonder there should be one file,why 2 ??